# derivation of nontrivial dependencies

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

I am seeking for help. I am stuck over a question based on functional dependency.

Consider the relation schema R= (A, B, C, D, E, G) and the set F of functional dependencies:
A → BC
BD → E
CD → AB
a. Derive the nontrivial dependencies from F using Armstrong’s axioms: AD → E and CD → E. Show all steps.

I can not understand the question. As per my understanding, here all functional dependencies are non trivial. So what is the meaning of Armstrong’s axioms: AD → E and CD → E.

Also, what is the meaning of derivation of nontrivial dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s try to derive AD → E from the [Armstrong’s axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong%27s_axioms) (I think this is the request of the exercise).

Here are the steps of derivation:

```
1. A → BC (given)
2. BD → E (given)
3. AD → BCD (for augmentation from 1)
4. BCD → BD (for reflexivity)
5. AD → BD (for transitivity from 3 and 4)
6. AD → E (for transitivity from 5 and 2)
```

I left the derivation of CD → E as exercise.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, So derivation means given the FD, A → BC BD → E CD → AB I need to find out how could I reach to AD->E and CD->E? Am I right? It helps me to learn from your derivation.

Comment: Yes, the exercise asked how to derive both AD->E and CD->E using the Armstrong’s axioms.

Comment: How can I get BCD->BD? Which functional dependency help to get this?

Comment: For BCD->BD means BD is the subset of BCD. Which functional dependency implies that?

Comment: The [reflexivity axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong%27s_axioms#Axiom_of_reflexivity) says: if Y is a subset of X, the X -> Y holds. Here BD is a subset of BCD.

Comment: For the second one CD->AB(given), CD ->A, CD->B (Decomposition)  CDD -> AD [Augmentation], CD->AD, AD->E then CD ->E [Transitivity].   Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.